# How to fix "Invalid frame type 21" error in Mautic

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-mq, mautic

I am trying to integrate AWS MQ (rabbitmq) with Mautic.

I updated local.php configuration file and provided RabbitMq details.

```
  'queue_protocol' => 'rabbitmq',
  'rabbitmq_host' => '*',
  'rabbitmq_port' => '5671',
  'rabbitmq_vhost' => '/',
  'rabbitmq_user' => '*',
  'rabbitmq_password' => '*',
  'rabbitmq_idle_timeout' => 0,
  'rabbitmq_idle_timeout_exit_code' => 0,
```

However each time an email is to be sent, I get:

```
[2023-06-22 11:54:13] mautic.CRITICAL: 
Uncaught PHP Exception PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPInvalidFrameException: "Invalid frame type 21" at /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php line 600 
{"exception":"[object] (PhpAmqpLib\\Exception\\AMQPInvalidFrameException(code: 0): Invalid frame type 21 at /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:600)"} 
{"hostname":"ip-10-1-1-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal","pid":984}
```

On AWS MQ side, I get

```
2023-06-22 11:45:59.217872+00:00 [notice] <0.4922.0> TLS server: In state hello at tls_record.erl:564 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Unexpected Message
2023-06-22 11:45:59.217872+00:00 [notice] <0.4922.0>  - {unsupported_record_type,65}
```

What I understand is, Mautic is doing non-ssl connection and AWS MQ is expecting ssl connection.

If this is the problem, how can I make Mautic make ssl enabled queue connections?